# Sitemap showing breakage in structure (layout) when adding hreflang

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, sitemap, hreflang

My Sitemap was showing correctly both its operation and its layout, but after inserting the attribute `xhtml:link rel="alternate"` the same start to be displayed in a strange way
[Sitemap structure with xtml:link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzVjn.png)

However, when checking the source code of this page, its content presents correctly.

- How to maintain the layout correctly? it looks like the Html is interpreting the attribute and breaking the layout;
- Does this affect the Site's performance on Google?

I expected the structure to be presented correctly